# Have a function fire once only at the beginning of the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Problem:** I have the following form below:

```js
var highlight = document.getElementById("miles").addEventListener("click", unHighlightMiles);

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $zip = $('#zip');
  var $city = $('#city');
  var $hospital = $('#hospital');
  var $miles = $('#miles');

  $zip.on("change",function(){
   $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
   $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $city.on("change",function(){
   $zip.val('').trigger('input');
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $hospital.on("change",function(){
   $zip.val('').trigger('input');
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });
  
  $miles.on("change", function(){
   $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
   $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
  });
 });

function checkTextField() {
  var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
  var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;

    if(zip && !distance){
   document.getElementById("miles").style.border = "1px solid red";
   var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
   alert(alertMessage);
   return false; //Does not submit form
  }
  else{
   if(zip && distance)
    return true;
  }
 }
 function unHighlightMiles(){
  document.getElementById("miles").style.border = "1px solid #cccccc";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
          <option value=""></option>
          <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
            <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
          </cfoutput>
        </select>
      </div>

      <hr />
      <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->
              <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance">
                <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
              </select>
              <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am having trouble with having the alert to appear when the user enters a zip code. By default, miles have a default of 5 which is fine. But when the form first appears, the mile section is blank. So when I enter the zip code, rather then showing the alert, it shows the results.

I was using the following:

```
$zip.one("change", function(){
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    })
```

which works fine because it only triggers once, however if the user selects mileage and then enters a zip code, the mileage will disappear do the function above.

How would I figure the function above only once if the user first decides to enter a zip code at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Maybe check to see if there's a value in miles and if so, don't change its val?

Comment: This might be helpful http://underscorejs.org/#once

Comment: @Snowmonkey: Can you show me? I feel I have done something like to validate but it fails

Comment: Well, where you do $miles.val('').trigger('input'); you are setting the value to nil and then triggering. Why do you set it to nil?

Comment: @TomCoughlin I do not want to load another library. Is it possible to use the before() feature though form Jquery and if so, breaking on me. Doing the following: $zip.before("change", function(){
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });

Comment: @Snowmonkey: You mean null? And if the value is '', then it triggers

Comment: But that's not what you're saying -- the code you've listed SETS the value to null, not CHECKS the value.

Comment: @Snowmonkey: Yes you are correct, it SETS the value to NULL and not CHECKS the value. I set it to NULL because if I have a value of null in my array, the way the program was design, it will crash the form. So, in the beginning, meaning when the form is generate, if the user selects the zip code and if the miles is empty, meaning user did not set a miles, show the alert. Otherwise, if both are selected, do not show alert. That is what I am trying to do with no sucess

Comment: Ah. so what about inside the $zip.on(...) function, you set $zip.off("change");  ? That would remove the event listener after it's been triggered. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: @Snowmonkey: I would like that be function to be on. I see how the .off() be helpful but I am trying to determine a validation where at the beginning of the page when it loads, if user enters zip, to have the one() function to set of, otherwise, do nothing

Comment: @Snowmonkey and @ TomCoughlin: Not able to see how to do it